# Changing same field name across many tables in a common database

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a database with over 400 tables. Each table has a Key ID field named different things but they all end with "Id". For example (not code):

```
Table 1 ID field = SurveyId
Table 2 ID field = TaskId
Table 3 ID Field = IWantAPeanutButterSandwichId
```

However, they are not the only fields in the table that contain "Id", so my first thought of incorporating a "Where name like '%Id'" will not be appropriate. Is there a way to identify through a sql query which field is the key field and have them all be changed to "Id" in one script" without having to go through each one individually?

Comment: I think it is much better to incorporate the table name into the id column, so foreign key relationships can usually use the same column name as the primary key.

Comment: I agree. If i were the guy designing it I would have done it that way, but i'm dealing with a pre-existing db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server metadata views (`information_schema.table_constraints` and `information_schema.constraint_column_usage`) to identify the key columns of your tables:

```
select 
    tc.table_schema, 
    tc.table_name,  
    ccu.column_name
from 
    information_schema.table_constraints as tc
        join 
    information_schema.constraint_column_usage as ccu 
        on tc.constraint_name = ccu.constraint_name
where  
    tc.constraint_type = 'Primary Key'
```